# close feh, and return to shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script that displays an image for a time, then returns back to the shell script. I tried:

```
feh outfile.jpeg | sleep 10 | exit
```

but this doesn't work. Im not interested in exiting the script, only in getting back to the other functions of the script. 
I just want to show the image for a short time, then return to what the script is doing. 
How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
feh outfile.jpeg &     # run process in background
pid=$!                 # obtain PID of last backgrounded process
sleep 10               
kill $pid              # kill feh
```

Comment: ((sleep 10 && killall display)&); display 2014.gif

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

```
(feh outfile.jpeg&) && (sleep 10 && pkill feh)
```

It will run `feh` in backgroud and then count to 10 before killing `feh`. A better way would be to kill the right pid though...